# Picture is not fit as want to

Tags: wrapfigure, paper-size

[image]Hello I put the image and test below codes but it is not adjusted as I want and it is smaller than expect or bigger. I need the picture cover half of the hight of the page at least.

```
![\begin{figure}\[h!\]
  \caption{State Diagram NIPT Algorithm}
  \centering
    \includegraphics\[width= 1\textwidth\]{bignipt_sep.eps}
    \includegraphics\[hight=1\]{bignipt_sep.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\[!ht\]
\begin{center}
\resizebox*{13cm}{!}
{\includegraphics\[scale= 0.5\]{bignipt_sep.eps}}\hspace{10pt}
\bf \caption{ State Diagram NIPT Algorithm}
\end{center}
\end{figure}][2]
```

Comment: Please provide a full example. You question is not clear. You talk about one image but include 3. "smaller than expect or bigger"? What do you mean by this?

Comment: I want to make it bigger but when I use the commands it exceed and go out of the page size.

Comment: The maximum width here is `\textwidth`. You should not use more. For the height, you will have to trial and error as the caption has to stay in the page limits as well. The package `showframe` helps you with this. You should only declare one size of the image and therefore I'd recommend the width.

Comment: The fonts in the image are so small. IMHO, the only chance for something readable is to put the image on a whole page in landscape mode, magnified as much as possible in the text area.

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % get rid of "demo" here!
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for demo
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.51\textheight]{bignipt_sep.eps}
    \caption{State Diagram NIPT Algorithm}\label{fig:bignipt}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have error when add this two packages:    \usepackage{blindtext} % just for demo
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

Comment: @mehdi what error? Have you installed that packages? Are you on MiKTeX or TeXlive?

Comment: when install packages and add the figure codes, face error on this line \usepackage{blindtext}  I add the error picture in next post.

Comment: I do not understand. Please ask a new question and explain exactly what you have done, what you have tried to fix that, and where you are stuck. The package `blindtext` is not needed here. It is just inserting some text when doing `\blindtext`. Get rid of both and insert the actual text you want to write.

Comment: but you add blindtext package in the code you add in this page.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % get rid of "demo" here!
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for demo
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.51\textheight]{bignipt_sep.eps}
    \caption{State Diagram NIPT Algorithm}\label{fig:bignipt}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}

Comment: @mehdi Yes, but just for demonstration. You can kick it out again. Btw. it has nothing to do with the error you are getting. The problem is the `demo` part of `graphicx` which you should kick out as well. I needed that option as I do not have `bignipt_sep.eps` here.